# Commiting changes to the sub-tree repo rather than the local one in git?

Tags: git, git-subtree

After one has created sub-tree repos in git, and re-checked out the code from all of the repos again, how do they do a commit and make sure that the changes get committed to their remote, but still keep them in sync with the local project?